# Pusher - adding ruby to javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

I'm trying to implement Pusher to my rails app and have it working in principal however I am struggling to add ruby code to the string of data being pushed to the client to create a url using link_to. I'm struggling to understand the problem as the javascript console is saying:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

```
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pusher = new Pusher('<%= Pusher.key %>'); // uses your API KEY
var channel = pusher.subscribe('worklink');
channel.bind('update', function(data) {

$("#comments").prepend(

"<div class='post_box'><div class='post'><p class='username'><b><%= link_to " + data.userfirstname + " " + data.userlastname + ", user_path(" + data.userid + ") %></b></p><p class='post_content'>" + data.postcontent + "</p></div></div>");

});
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't pass your JavaScript variables to Ruby code. You need to do vise-a-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surya is right on; you'll need to construct the link in ruby, then pass it out as javascript.

Assuming you have a @user variable populated in your view (perhaps you can use `current_user`?):

```
var prependLink = "<%= link_to "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}", user_path(@user) %>"
$('#comments').prepend(prependLink);
```